# Script <SCRIPT_NAME> is broken: missing end of LSB comment

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am getting this error when running:

- insserv -r udo-startup.sh
  insserv: Script udo-startup.sh is broken: missing end of LSB comment.
  insserv: exiting now!

The content of udo-startup.sh is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          udo-startup.sh
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6 
# Short-Description: -
# Description:       -
### END INIT INF

ID=$(xinput list | grep -i touchpad | sed '/TouchPad/s/^.*id=\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/')
xinput set-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 0

exit 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are missing last "O" in comment section ("### END INIT INF" -> "### END INIT INFO")

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this when googleing this error message in the future:

I just encountered this error when I accidentally saved the file with the wrong line termination.  I accidentally flipped it off LF and saved as CR and received this error.